# Inequality with $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$ condition

Tags: inequality

> For $x,y,z \geqslant 0$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$, prove that
>   $$ 4(xy+yz+zx-xyz) \geqslant (x^2y+z)(y^2z+x)(z^2x+y)$$

**Observations**

1. The condition $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$ is special. One can use the transformation $x=2cosA,y=2cosB,z=2cosC$ and the identity
   $$cos^2A+cos^2B+cos^2C+2cosAcosBcosC =1$$ to solve the equivalent trig inequality. I attempted to go this road and used Blandon inequality, but it was too much computation.
2. The condition reminds us about the USAMO 2001 inequality. USAMO2001 stated that $$2\geqslant xy+yz+zx-xyz$$
   sadly the sign is reversed.
3. This is a cyclic inequality. I don't think the trick of rewrite the inequality to $xyz \text{ }$,$ xy+yz+zx\text{ }$,$\text{ }x+y+z \text{ }$ worked here.

Comment: Try finding a solution (like $x=y=z=1$) and check if it is a global solution and check derivatives

Comment: here's a good one: figure out how to construct all solutions, in positive integers, of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3xyz$

Comment: try this :$a=\dfrac{x}{yz},b=\dfrac{y}{xz},c=\dfrac{z}{xy}$, I am not sure it works, but it can simplify the inequality.

Comment: Look there: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805719/prove-sqrt2xy-sqrt3yz-sqrt4zx-4/1847546#1847546

Comment: Maybe we may replace the RHS with a symmetric form.