# Prove $\sqrt[2]{x+y}+\sqrt[3]{y+z}+\sqrt[4]{z+x} <4$

Tags: inequality

> $x,y,z \geqslant 0$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$, prove
>   $$\sqrt[2]{x+y}+\sqrt[3]{y+z}+\sqrt[4]{z+x} <4$$

A natural though is that from the condition $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$, I tried a trig substitutions $x=2\cdot \cos A$, $y=2\cdot \cos B$ and $z=2\cdot \cos C$, where $A,B,C$ are angles of an acute triangle.

Our inequality becomes
$$\sqrt[2]{2(\cos A+ \cos B)}+\sqrt[3]{2(\cos B+\cos C)}+\sqrt[4]{2(\cos C+\cos A)} <4$$

I used formula $\cos(A)+\cos(B) < 2$ and estimate that $LHS <5$ but not $4$.
I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Perhaps the Lagrange multipliers  method will help to find the LHS max.

Answer (score 4):

The condition $\;x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4\;$ can be rewritten as:
$$
z^2+xy\cdot z + (x^2+y^2-4) = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad
z = - \frac{xy}{2} \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{xy}{2}\right)^2-(x^2+y^2-4)}
$$
From $z \ge 0$ it follows that:
$$
z = - \frac{xy}{2} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{xy}{2}\right)^2-(x^2+y^2-4)} \quad \mbox{and} \quad x^2+y^2\le 4
$$
Therefore, after substitution of $\,z$ ,
we only have to investigate function behavior
$f(x,y) = \sqrt[2]{x+y}+\sqrt[3]{y+z}+\sqrt[4]{z+x} < 4$
in the area enclosed by x-axis, y-axis and a quarter of a circle, as depicted below.

[image]

Another [proof without words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_without_words) is attempted
by plotting a contour map of the function, as depicted. Levels (`nivo`) of these isolines are defined
(in Delphi Pascal) as:

```
nivo := min + g/grens*(max-min); { grens = 40 ; g = 1..grens }
```

The blackness of the isolines is proportional to the (positive) function values; they are almost white
near the minimum and almost black near the maximum values.
Maximum and minimum values of the function are observed to be:

```
 2.54387743763872E+0000 < f < 3.91477606446737E+0000
```

The $\color{blue}{\mbox{blue}}$ spot is where $\,\left| f(x,y) - 4 \right| < 0.9$ .
It is suggested by the rather large error $\,0.9\,$ that $\,4\,$ is not really the maximum.
Indeed, upon refinement of the grid we find for the maximum numerically (double precision)
a somewhat lower value:

```
3.91477205860402 < 4
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution of 18.07.16**

Using OP idea.

Let
$$u=\dfrac{x}2,\quad v=\dfrac{y}2,$$
then translate the condition in form
$$4u^2+4v^2+z^2+4uvz=4,$$
$$(z+2uv)^2 = 4(1-u^2)(1-v^2),$$
$$z=2\sqrt{(1-u^2)(1-v^2)}-2uv \leq (1-u^2)+(1-v^2)-2uv,$$
$$z\leq2-(u+v)^2.$$
So we can prove inequality
$$\sqrt[2]{2(u+v)}+\sqrt[3]{2v+2-(u+v)^2}+\sqrt[4]{2u+2-(u+v)^2} < 4.$$
Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we get
$$\left(\sqrt[2]{2(u+v)}+\sqrt[3]{2v+2-(u+v)^2}+\sqrt[4]{2u+2-(u+v)^2}\right)^2$$
$$\leq (\sqrt[2]4+\sqrt[3]4+\sqrt[4]4)\left(u+v+\left(v+1-\dfrac12(u+v)^2\right)^{2/3}+\left(u+1-\dfrac12(u+v)^2\right)^{1/2}\right) < 16.$$
Maximal value of
$$f(u,v) = u+v+\left(v+1-\dfrac12(u+v)^2\right)^{2/3}+\left(u+1-\dfrac12(u+v)^2\right)^{1/2}$$
can be achieved in local extremum within the area $u,v\in[0,1],$ or in the edges of the area.

The nesessary conditions of local extremum are
$$f'_u=0,\quad f'_v=0,$$
or
$$\begin{cases}
1+\dfrac23\dfrac{-u-v}{\sqrt[3]{v+1-\dfrac12(u+v)^2}}+\dfrac12\dfrac{1-u-v}{\sqrt{u+1-\dfrac12(u+v)^2}} = 0\\
1+\dfrac23\dfrac{1-u-v}{\sqrt[3]{v+1-\dfrac12(u+v)^2}}+\dfrac12\dfrac{-u-v}{\sqrt{u+1-\dfrac12(u+v)^2}} = 0,\\
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
-u-v & 1-u-v\\
1-u-v & -u-v
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac2{3\sqrt[3]{v+1-\dfrac12(u+v)^2}}\\
\dfrac1{2\sqrt{u+1-\dfrac12(u+v)^2}}
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Solving this linear system by Cramer's rule, we obtain:
$$
\Delta =
\begin{vmatrix}
-u-v & 1-u-v\\
1-u-v & -u-v
\end{vmatrix}
= 2u+2v-1,
$$
$$
\Delta_1 =
\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & 1-u-v\\
-1 & -u-v
\end{vmatrix}
= 1,
$$
$$
\Delta_2 =
\begin{vmatrix}
-u-v & -1\\
1-u-v & -1
\end{vmatrix}
= 1,
$$
$$\begin{cases}
3\sqrt[3]{v+1-\dfrac12(u+v)^2}= 2(2u+2v-1)\\
2\sqrt{u+1-\dfrac12(u+v)^2}= 2u+2v-1
\end{cases}$$
If $$2(u+v)\geq1,$$ then
$$\begin{cases}
27\left(2v+2-(u+v)^2\right)=16(2u+2v-1)^3\\
2\left(2u+2-(u+v)^2\right)=(2u+2v-1)^2,
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
108\left(u+v+2-(u+v)^2\right)=32(2u+2v-1)^3+27(2u+2v-1)^2\qquad[2\times(1)+27\times(2)]\\
2\left(2u+2-(u+v)^2\right)=(2u+2v-1)^2.
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
256(u+v)^3-168(u+v)^2-24(u+v)-221 = 0\\
u = \dfrac14(6(u+v)^2-4(u+v)-3)
\end{cases}$$

Cubic equation 
$$256s^3-168s^2-24s-221 = 0$$
has one real [root](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=256s%5E3-168s%5E2-24s-221%20%3D%200)
$$s = \dfrac1{32}\left(7+3^{5/3}\sqrt[3]{61-8\sqrt{58}}+3^{5/3}\sqrt[3]{61+8\sqrt{58}}\right),$$ 
so $f(u,v)$ has the unique extremum
$$(u,v,f) \approx(0.392428, 0.875106, 3.08237).$$

The edges of the field achieves when $u\in\{0,1\}$ or $v\in\{0,1\}.$

$$f(0,v) = v + (v+1-\dfrac12v^2)^(2/3) + (1-\dfrac12v^2)^(1/2)$$ 
has the global [maximum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%20v%20%2B%20(v%2B1-%5Cdfrac12v%5E2)%5E(2%2F3)%20%2B%20(1-%5Cdfrac12v%5E2)%5E(1%2F2)) $\approx3.03678,$ so
$$f(0,v) < 3.08237.$$

$$f(1,v) = v+1 + (v+1-\dfrac12(1+v)^2)^(2/3) + (2-\dfrac12(1+v)^2)^(1/2)$$ 
has the [global maximum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%20v%2B1%20%2B%20(v%2B1-%5Cdfrac12(1%2Bv)%5E2)%5E(2%2F3)%20%2B%20(2-%5Cdfrac12(1%2Bv)%5E2)%5E(1%2F2)) $\approx 2.9714,$ so
$$f(1,v) < 3.08237.$$

$$f(u,0) = u + (1-\dfrac12u^2)^(2/3) + (1+u-\dfrac12u^2)^(1/2)$$ 
has the [global](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%20u%20%2B%20(1-%5Cdfrac12u%5E2)%5E(2%2F3)%20%2B%20(1%2Bu-%5Cdfrac12u%5E2)%5E(1%2F2)) maximum $\approx 2.86142,$ so
$$f(u,0) < 3.08237.$$

$$f(u,1) = u+1 + (2-\dfrac12(u+1)^2)^(2/3) + (u+1-\dfrac12(u+1)^2)^(1/2)$$ 
has [the global maximum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%20u%2B1%20%2B%20(2-%5Cdfrac12(u%2B1)%5E2)%5E(2%2F3)%20%2B%20(u%2B1-%5Cdfrac12(u%2B1)%5E2)%5E(1%2F2)) $\approx 3.07604,$ so
$$f(u,1) < 3.08237.$$
Note that 
$$f(0,0)=2,\quad f(0,1)\approx 3.017477,\quad f(1,0)\approx 2.854705, \quad f(1,1)=2.$$

Given the conditions and the accuracy of the calculations this means that
$$f(u,v) < 3.08238,$$
$$\left(\sqrt[2]{2(u+v)}+\sqrt[3]{2v+2-(u+v)^2}+\sqrt[4]{2u+2-(u+v)^2}\right)^2 < 3.08238\left(\sqrt[2]4+\sqrt[3]4+\sqrt[4]4\right) < 15.4169,$$
$$\sqrt[2]{2(u+v)}+\sqrt[3]{2v+2-(u+v)^2}+\sqrt[4]{2u+2-(u+v)^2} < 3.926,$$
and for $\quad x,y,z \geq 0,\quad x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$
$$\boxed{\sqrt[2]{x+y}+\sqrt[3]{y+z}+\sqrt[4]{z+x}<4.}$$

Answer (score 1):

Remark: My second proof is given in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2483725p20868007.
There, KaiRain@AoPS gave a nice proof.

**Proof without using derivative**

We split into three cases:

1. $y+z \le 1$ and $z+x \le 1$: We have $x + y \le 2$.
   Thus, we have $\mathrm{LHS} \le \sqrt{2} + 1 + 1 < 4$. The inequality is true.
2. $y + z > 1$ and $z + x \le 1$: Since $\sqrt[3]{y+z} < \sqrt{y+z}$ and $\sqrt[4]{z+x} \le 1$, it suffices to prove that
   $$\sqrt{x+y} + \sqrt{y+z} \le 3.$$
   By AM-QM inequality, we have $\sqrt{x+y} + \sqrt{y+z} \le \sqrt{2(x+y + y + z)}$. Thus,
   It suffices to prove that $$x+2y+z \le \frac{9}{2}.$$
   From $x^2+y^2+z^2 + xyz = 4$, we have
   $y^2 + (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{y}{4})(x + z)^2 + (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{y}{4})(x - z)^2 = 4$
   which results in $y^2 + (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{y}{4})(x + z)^2 \le 4$
   and $x + z \le \sqrt{\frac{4(4 - y^2)}{2 + y}}$.
   Thus, it suffices to prove that $2y + \sqrt{\frac{4(4 - y^2)}{2 + y}} \le \frac{9}{2}$.
   It suffices to prove that $(\frac{9}{2} - 2y)^2 \ge \frac{4(4 - y^2)}{2 + y}$
   that is $\frac{1}{4}(4y - 7)^2 \ge 0$. The inequality is true.
3. $z + x > 1$: Since $\sqrt[3]{z+x} > \sqrt[4]{z+x}$, it suffices to prove that
   $$
   \sqrt{x+y}  + \sqrt[3]{y+z} + \sqrt[3]{z+x} < 4.
   $$
   Note that $u\mapsto \sqrt[3]{u}$ is concave on $u > 0$.
   It suffices to prove that
   $$
   \sqrt{x+y}  + 2\sqrt[3]{\frac{y+z + z+x}{2}} < 4.
   $$
   From $x^2+y^2+z^2 + xyz = 4$, we have $(z + \frac{1}{2}xy)^2 = \frac{1}{4}(4-x^2)(4-y^2)$
   which results in $$z = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(4-x^2)(4-y^2)}-\frac{1}{2}xy \le \frac{1}{2}\frac{4-x^2+4-y^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2}xy  = 2- \frac{(x+y)^2}{4}.$$
   Thus, it suffices to prove that
   $$
   \sqrt{x+y}  + 2\sqrt[3]{\frac{y+x}{2} + 2- \frac{(x+y)^2}{4}} < 4.
   $$
   Let $v = \sqrt{x+y}$. Since $x+y \le \sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)} \le \sqrt{2 \cdot 4} < 4$, we have $v\in (0, 2)$.
   It suffices to prove that $$v + 2\sqrt[3]{\frac{v^2}{2} + 2- \frac{v^4}{4}} < 4$$
   or $$\frac{v^2}{2} + 2- \frac{v^4}{4} < \frac{1}{8}(4 - v)^3$$ or $$\frac{1}{8}(2v^4-v^3+8v^2-48v+48) > 0$$ for $v\in (0, 2)$.
   It is easy to prove that $2v^4-v^3+8v^2-48v+48 > 0$ for $v\in (0, 2)$.
   We are done.

Comment: Mr. @RiverLi , your observations always inspires me !

Comment: I'm looking for your solution with $\lceil$ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3279595/685744 $\rfloor$ , thanks

Comment: @GiangNguyễnĐặngThanh    Thank you for the kind words.

Comment: @GiangNguyễnĐặngThanh  That idea is simple but powerful: To prove $A \ge 0$, we find $P, Q, M, N \ge 0$ and $k$ such that $A = k P + Q$ and $A = -k M + N$.
Then $A = \frac{QM + PN}{P+M} \ge 0$. That problem is hard for me. Michael Rozenberg gave a nice solution.

Comment: @GiangNguyễnĐặngThanh  By the way, Baoqian Liu's result is nice: $(xyz + x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)^4 \ge \frac{256}{27}(x+y+z)^3 (xyz)^3$. Sometimes, it is not very hard to prove an inequality, but it is very hard to propose it.

Comment: (+1). Very nice solution. Thank you very much. My sol is to use geometry, which is also very short.

Comment: @HN_NH  You are welcome. Your solution is the best since it is **very short**.

Answer (score 0):

**PARTIAL SOLUTION**

$$f(x,y,z)=\sqrt[2]{x+y}+\sqrt[3]{y+z}+\sqrt[4]{z+x}$$
$$g(x,y,z)= x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz-4=0$$
$$ \begin{align}\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda) =& \;f(x,y,z) + \lambda g(x,y,z)\\
=&\;\sqrt[2]{x+y}+\sqrt[3]{y+z}+\sqrt[4]{z+x}+\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz-4) \end{align}$$
$$\nabla_{x,y,z,\lambda}\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda) =\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x},\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y},\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial z},\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda}\right)$$
Now comes the work finding the partial derivatives

$$\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} =\; \lambda(2x+yz) + \frac{1}{2(x+y)^{1/2}}+\frac{1}{4(x+z)^{3/4}}\\
&\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y} =\; \lambda(2y+xz) + \frac{1}{2(x+y)^{1/2}}+\frac{1}{3(y+z)^{2/3}}\\
&\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial z} =\; \lambda(2z+xy) + \frac{1}{3(y+z)^{2/3}}+\frac{1}{4(x+z)^{3/4}}\\
&\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda} =\; x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz-4
\end{align}$$

$$\nabla_{x,y,z,\lambda}\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda)=0 \iff \begin{cases}
\lambda(2x+yz) + \frac{1}{2(x+y)^{1/2}}+\frac{1}{4(x+z)^{3/4}}  & = 0 \\
\lambda(2y+xz) + \frac{1}{2(x+y)^{1/2}}+\frac{1}{3(y+z)^{2/3}} & = 0 \\
\lambda(2z+xy) + \frac{1}{3(y+z)^{2/3}}+\frac{1}{4(x+z)^{3/4}}  & = 0 \\
x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz-4, & = 0
\end{cases}$$
At this point I cannot seem to solve the resulting equations. The symmetry involved implies some simple trick should suffice, though I have yet to spot one.

Comment: Look at the second equation in your last system. I think there is a typo

Comment: @YuriyS hmm... there is no typo I can find. I checked them thoroughly. Note that the first three equations in the last system go through all three unique combinations of $a$, $b$, and $c$, where the letters represent the fractions. I could reorder the fractions to make this clearer, but that doesn't make the equations incorrect. What do you believe was the error I made?

Comment: I meant the term $\frac{1}{2(x+y)^{1/2}}$ which is the same in both first and second equations. I thought it was a typo, but I didn't check your derivation, so it's likely I'm mistaken.