# Given three positive numbers $x,y,z$, prove that $(xyz+x^{2}y+y^{2}z+z^{2}x)^{4}\geqq\frac{256}{27}(x+y+z)^{3}x^{3}y^{3}z^{3}$ .

Tags: inequality, triangles, substitution, geometric-inequalities, uvw

> ***Hint.*** *Given three length-sides* $a, b, c$ *of a triangle. For* $\Delta= \sqrt{s(s- a)(s- b)(s- c)}$*, prove :*
>   $$abc+ (a- b)(b- c)(c- a)\geqq \frac{8}{3}\sqrt{\sqrt{3}\Delta^{3}} \tag{1}$$
>   $$abc- (a- b)(b- c)(c- a)\geqq \frac{8}{3}\sqrt{\sqrt{3}\Delta^{3}} \tag{2}$$

***Remark.*** *Given four positive numbers* $b, c, d, e$ *so that* $ab+ c= -ad+ e$ *(as inequalties above) :*
$$\therefore\,ab+ c= -ad+ e= \frac{eb+ cd}{b+ d}\geqq 0$$
*After using* $\lceil$ **Ravi-substitution** $\rfloor$ *and more, we have a problem due to Liu Qian Bao as follow :*

> ***Problem.*** *Given three positive numbers $x, y, z$, prove that :*
>   $$(xyz+ x^{2}y+ y^{2}z+ z^{2}x)^{4}\geqq \frac{256}{27}(x+ y+ z)^{3}x^{3}y^{3}z^{3}$$

*I think the best way here is to prove* $(1)$ and $(2)$ *by* $uvw$ *because they're* $cyc$, *but hard to square them*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's true by the $uvw$'s technique.

Indeed, let $x+y+z=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$, $abc=w^3$ and $u=t^{\frac{4}{3}}w$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$w^3+\sum_{cyc}x^2y\geq4\sqrt[4]{u^3w^9}$$ or
$$2w^3+\sum_{cyc}(x^2y+x^2z)-8\sqrt[4]{u^3w^9}\geq\sum_{cyc}(x^2z-x^2y)$$ or
$$9uv^2-w^3-8\sqrt[4]{u^3w^9}\geq(x-y)(y-z)(z-x).$$
Now, since by Maclaurin
$$9uv^2-w^3-8\sqrt[4]{u^3w^9}\geq0,$$ it's enough to prove that
$$\left(9uv^2-w^3-8\sqrt[4]{u^3w^9}\right)^2\geq\prod_{cyc}(x-y)^2(x-z)^2(y-z)^2$$ or
$$\left(9uv^2-w^3-8\sqrt[4]{u^3w^9}\right)^2\geq27(3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6)$$ or
$$27v^6-(45uv^2w^3+36uv^2\sqrt[4]{u^3w^9})v^2+7w^6+27u^3w^3+4w^3\sqrt[4]{u^3w^9}+16\sqrt{u^3w^9}\geq0.$$
Now, by AM-GM
$$27v^6+7w^6+27u^3w^3+4w^3\sqrt[4]{u^3w^9}+16\sqrt{u^3w^9}=$$
$$=27v^6+2\cdot\frac{7w^6+27u^3w^3+4w^3\sqrt[4]{u^3w^9}+16\sqrt{u^3w^9}}{2}\geq$$
$$\geq3\sqrt[3]{27v^6\cdot\left(\frac{7w^6+27u^3w^3+4w^3\sqrt[4]{u^3w^9}+16\sqrt{u^3w^9}}{2}\right)^2}.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$3\sqrt[3]{27v^6\cdot\left(\frac{7w^6+27u^3w^3+4w^3\sqrt[4]{u^3w^9}+16\sqrt{u^3w^9}}{2}\right)^2}\geq(45uv^2w^3+36uv^2\sqrt[4]{u^3w^9})v^2$$ or
$$(27t^4+16t^2+14t+7)^2\geq4t^4(4t+5)^3$$ or $f(t)\geq0,$ where
$$f(t)=2\ln(27t^4+16t^2+4t+7)-4\ln{t}-3\ln(4t+5)-2\ln2.$$
Now, $$f'(t)=\frac{2(108t^3+32t+4)}{27t^4+16t^2+4t+7}-\frac{4}{t}-\frac{12}{4t+5}=$$
$$=\frac{4(t-1)(27t^4+162t^3+114t^2+94t+35)}{t(4t+5)(27t^4+16t^2+4t+7)},$$ which gives $t_{\min}=1$ and since $f(1)=0$, we are done!

Comment: I think you meant to write $u=t^{4/3}w$ in your second line. Nice proof!

Comment: @SystematicDisintegration It was typo. I fixed. Thank you!